# Differences between the Rosh HaShanah service Ashkenaz/Sefard

Tags: prayer-book, rosh-hashanah-new-year, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard

Besides the usual differences that differentiate between Nusach Ashkenaz and Sefard, such as the different order of Shacharis, extra words here and there, etc. are there any major differences between a RH machzor that is nusach Ashkenaz versus one that is Sefard?

Follow up question here: [Differences between the Yom Kippur service Ashkenaz/Sefard](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85381/differences-between-the-yom-kippur-service-ashkenaz-sefard)

Comment: Are you asking specifically about RH Machzorim or also Yom Kippur's?

Comment: @DoubleAA - If I had meant YK, I would have mentioned YK. I said for RH, because I think putting RH and YK together would be too overwhelming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Amidot of the Yamim Nora'im, in the blessing *Kdushat Hashem*, in Nusah Sfard four paragraphs beginning ובכן are added. In Nusah Ashkenaz, three are added.

In Avinu Malkeinu on Rosh HaShanah, in Nusah Sfard the custom is to omit the petitions that mention sin (I don't know if this is true for all editions of Nusah Sfard). In Nusah Ashkenaz the petitions are recited.

In the silent Amidah of Rosh HaShanah Musaf, in Nusah Sfard the shofar is sounded after each of the three middle blessings, and the paragraph *HaYom Harat Olam* is recited by each individual at each of those points (though in the nusah of the B'al Ha-Tanya, the paragraph is not recited). In Nusah Ashkenaz there is no sounding of the shofar in the silent Amidah.

I don't think differences in the selection of the piyyutim for Rosh HaShanah break down by Nusah Sfard/Ashkenaz distinction. (But for Yom Kippur, there is a distinction in the selection of the piyyut used for the Avodah in Musaf).

Comment: Can you provide a link to one of the sources that you used. I'm not sure if each of what you mentioned is followed universally by all Nusach Sefard (Aka "Nusach Ari". I'm not referring to Edot Hamizrach, or other Sefardi communities / minhagim.)

Answer (score 2):

Psalm 27 will be recited at mincha in nusach sfard congregations and at arvit in nusach asheknaz congregations so it will be in mincha in sfard machzorim and at arvit in ashkenazi communities. 
If rosh hashanah falls out on shabbat nusach ashkenaz starts kabbalat shabbat at mizmor shel leyom hashabbat and nusach sfard starts with mizmor ledavid so again the nusach ashkenaz machzor wont have mizmor ledavid and the stanzas of lecha dodi that are said in nusach sfard.