# Differences between the Yom Kippur service Ashkenaz/Sefard

Tags: prayer-book, yom-kippur, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard

Follow up question of [Differences between the Rosh HaShanah service Ashkenaz/Sefard](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85372/differences-between-the-rosh-hashanah-service-ashkenaz-sefard/85373#85373).

Besides the usual differences that differentiate between Nusach Ashkenaz and Sefard, such as the different order of Shacharis, extra words here and there, etc. are there any major differences between a YK machzor that is nusach Ashkenaz versus one that is Sefard?

Comment: I'll try to verify, later, B"N. I think a major difference can be found in the version and selection of piyuttim used in the *Avodah* section of Musaph. I also think there are some differences in a few items in Ne'ilah.

Comment: 1. pyutim and slichot and kel melech yoshev and the passage after 13 midot are different, the seder haavoda is the same that in nusach sfard. the show is entirely different.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest difference is that there is an entirely different Avoda. Ashkenazim say [אמיץ כח](http://web.nli.org.il/sites/nlis/he/Song/Pages/Song.aspx?SongID=4284#3,138,9140,74), while Sefaradim say [אתה כוננת](http://web.nli.org.il/sites/nlis/he/Song/Pages/Song.aspx?SongID=5347#1,13,9141,11). Some prayer books (at least Koren and artscroll) include the second version as an appendix.

Apparently, apart from [אמיץ כח](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22323&st=&pgnum=490), some German Jews said a different version beginning [אשוחח נפלאותיך](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22323&st=&pgnum=502), while French Jews used to say another version beginning [אתה כוננת](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22323&st=&pgnum=520) (different from the Spanish version).

The first lines from each:

German/Polish

> אַמִּיץ כֹּחַ כַּבִּיר וְרַב אוֹנִים,  אֲשֶׁר מִי יַעֲשֶׂה כְּמַעַש גְּבוּרוֹתֶיךָ, 
>   אֹמֶץ עֲלִיּוֹת קֵרִיתָ עַל קָרִים, אַף יִסַּדְתָּ תֵבֵל עַל בְּלִימָה.

Alternate German

> אשוחח נפלאותיך צור עולמים, אהג מפעלותיך אדיר במרומים, אדברה גבורותיך בארש נעימים, אזכירה תהלתך קצת מעצומים

French

> אתה כוננת עולם ברב חסד, ובו יתנהג עד קץ הימים, אשר לא ימוט מעון היצורים, ולא ימעד מכובד פשע וחטאים

Spanish

> אַתָּה כּוֹנַנְתָּ עוֹלָם מֵרֹאשׁ, יָסַדְתָּ תֵּבֵל וְהַכֹּל פָּעַלְתָּ וּבְרִיּוֹת בּוֹ יָצַרְתָּ. 
>   בְּשׁוּרְךָ עוֹלָם תֹּהוּ וָבֹהוּ וְחֹשֶׁךְ עַל פְּנֵי תְהוֹם, גֵּרַשְׁתָּ אֹפֶל וְהִצַּבְתָּ נֹגַהּ.

Comment: You know when I said "Sefard" I meant Nusach Sefard not Nusach Edot HaMizrach, the nusach of the Sephardim, right?

Comment: @ezra It's described as סדר העבודה ספרד

Answer (score 0):

Kol Nidre is different, Different order of verses.